# Magento Own Module Controller leads to 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create my own Magento Module. It should print out a simple "Hello World".
I've tried to call my Module with the following URLs:

- http://127.0.0.1/magento/echo/echo
- //127.0.0.1/magento/echo/echo/index
- //127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/echo/echo
- //127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/echo/echo/index

Every single URL leads to the 404 page.

I created the following files:

app/etc/modules/Webshop_Echo.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Webshop_Echo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Webshop_Echo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Webshop/Echo/etc/config.xml

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Webshop_Echo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Webshop_Echo>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <echo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Webshop_Echo</module>
                    <frontName>echo</frontName>
                </args>
            </echo>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
 </config>
```

app/code/local/Webshop/controller/EchoController.php

```
<?php
class Webshop_Echo_EchoController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following controller location

```
app/code/local/Webshop/controller/EchoController.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Webshop/controllers/EchoController.php
```

Notice the directory name : **controllers**